# org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl : Memory usage of ProcessTree

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm submitting a simple wordcount application to YARN.

I get this application status `ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM.`

But checking in the NodeManager logs shows that a container has actually being allocated. 
Here's the redundant line of the NM's log : (It also shows LAUNCHED container on web UI)

```
   2018-02-02 21:34:52,981 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 4489 for container-id container_1517605293649_0003_02_02_000001: 249.6 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 1.5 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
```

Here's my Yarn-site.xml:

```
 <configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>6144</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>vanillacluster-vanilla-default-master-0</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.nodes.exclude-path</name>
    <value>/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/nm-exclude</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.nodes.include-path</name>
    <value>/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/nm-include</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>6144</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>512</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

And my mapred-site.xml

```
 <configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx409m</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>512</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx819m</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>1024</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb</name>
    <value>204</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx819m</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I can't spot the problem, since my available memory is at least twice more than required.

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Click the link to go to the application ID, then look at the application master's, or attempt logs

Comment: Seems weird, thought ResourceManager was working only on 8032, I had to open the 4 ports the process was using (8030,8031,8032,8033) then the container registered in RM.